# I want to fix in a position my "Drawings button" in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

*I want to fix my "Drawings Button" to one position in google sheets so that when I scroll through the sheet they are always in the same position as a menu
so... the user always has the options available in front of him.*

This is the link for my sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YJZlonIYi4c2H_NRfXQtMBPD8MTtM5KQcCtyjYiUca0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Aside from freezing the top row and moving the buttons just like @marikamitsos answer below, do you consider using a custom side bar for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can freeze your top rows and put them inside.

[image]

Comment: It may be an option... but the space of the sheets decreases too much